# rails puma nginx development mode localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

the scenario is that I have created a instance on aws and on that clone my rails project and run using rails s command on localhost:3000. and the server is running using PUMA.

now I want to see my app running on public DNS that is http://ec2-13-56-156-255.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

for that I have install the nginx web server and I am able to see the default index page of nginx but when I am making change to see my app in nginx.conf file it is giving me 403 error. changes are as follows.

file path: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

---

```
user ec2-user;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
 worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
 "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;


include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
index   index.html index.htm;

upstream app {
 server 127.0.0.1:3000;
 #server unix:///path_to_my_app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  13.56.156.255;
    root        /home/ec2-user/Projects/aqua_web_v1.0;
    #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

   #location / {
   #}

   location @app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;        
      proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
```

---

Comment: Do you try run rails from console like `rails s`?

Comment: yes @kunashir from console on aws instance.

Comment: try `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: tried still getting 403 Forbidden error

Answer (score 0):

you need to create server block config file by copying over the default file:

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

now open that file with `sudo` previlege

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

and then add your host name to:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

for more details checkout this digitalocean guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: server_name should be localhost?

Comment: server_name should be localhost? and it is necessary to create the block can we not do configuration in ngnix.conf only file in my case because I simple want to see my app which is running on local to the public dns